# Where do I find "log in" and "register" link which are located on the top right corner?

Tags: login, links, user-registration

My site has "log in" and "register" links on the top right corner of homepage and every page. Where do I find these in the source code?

Comment: please define your site url.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look for `wp_registration_url()` and `wp_login_url( ... )` functions inside your code.

Answer (score 0):

These must have been added by your theme. Have a look at functions.php in your theme folder (wp-content/themes/) and search for the above methods.